# Linear Response for Fermi Gas at $T=0$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter

I want to solve with linear response theory the Kubo formula for a non-interacting Fermi gas at $T=0$. First of all I'm not quite sure how to write down the integral. Basically the one can derive that Kubo formula in Lehmann representation gives us: 
$$\Pi_0=-\frac{1}{V}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\frac{n_{\mathbf{k}}-n_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{q}}}{\omega+\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}}-\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{q}}+i\eta} $$
with $\epsilon_{k}=\mathbf{k}^{2}/2m$. 
Now I want to go into the continuous limit and solving the integral:
\begin{align*}
\Pi_{0}(\mathbf{q},\omega) &=-\frac{1}{V}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\frac{ n_{\mathbf{k}}-n_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{q}}}{\omega+\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}}-\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{q}}+i\eta} \\
&\overset{?}= \int\frac{\mathrm{d}^{3}\mathbf{k}}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{  \theta(|\mathbf{k+q}|-k_F ) -\theta(|\mathbf{k}| -k_F) }{\omega+\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}}-\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{q}}+i\eta}
\end{align*}
I assumed that $n_{\mathbf k} \overset{T=0}\to \theta(\mathbf k-k_F)$, but I'm not sure about it. The energy can be written as 
$$\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}}-\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{q}} =\frac{\mathbf k^{2}}{2m}- \frac{(\mathbf k+\mathbf q)^{2}}{2m} = - \frac{1}{m} \left(\mathbf{k q} + \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{q}^{2}\right)$$
I think the main idea is to find $\textrm{Re}\Pi_{0}(\mathbf{q},\omega)$ and $\textrm{Im}\Pi_{0}(\mathbf{q},\omega)$ solve them separately. The principal value could be also used.  Has someone maybe an easy approach to this?

Comment: See Section 4.4 of "Quantum Theory of the Electron Liquid" by Giuliani and Vignale.